# Асинхронное выполнение задач PHP

Tags: php, crontab

Как сделать как на видео:

[Видео вопрос](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rwp0TOWk2Yw&)

На случай если видео станет недоступно:
Есть БД. В ней находятся ID групп.
В каждой итерации цикл передаёт ID группы в функцию.
Функция начинает выполнять разные условия, запросы, записи в БД.
Это занимает N-ое количество времени. 
И так на каждой итерации.

Такой метод получается последовательный.

Как сделать так что бы сначала прогрузились ID групп, а потом одновременно начались выполнения функций.

Comment: Внимание на экран! Видео-вопрос!

Comment: @cppquestions Так а что не так то? :)

Comment: Вопрос должен быть в текстовой форме. Опишите свою проблему максимально подробно, желательно с кодом. Если этого будет недостаточно, в качестве дополнительного источника дайте ссылку на видео

Comment: @cppquestions К чему такие ограничения, я решил что на видео про вопрос объясню больше не же ли я бы это делал в текстовом формате.

Comment: К тому, что вопросы, состоящие из "как сделать X + ссылка", не несут пользы для сообщества. Ссылка станет нерабочей через какое-то время, и вопрос станет абсолютно бесполезным

Comment: Для информации, вк вас забанит за столь эффективное получение информации, так что все усилия все равно окажутся бессмысленными.

Comment: @cppquestions дополнил ответ.

Comment: @Ипатьев 3 запроса в секунду вк разрешает. Делаются в нужных местах sleep, а так же группы выполняются из под разных приложений. Что снимает количество запросов. Это уже проверено и работает. Я решил это проблему через crontab, создал несколько файлов, и на каждый такой файл выделил условно говоря по 5 групп. Но так получается слишком много однотипных файлов и каждый приходиться прописывать в задачу crontab.Потому ищу более универсальный способ. Лучше скажите как сделать так как я спрашиваю.

Comment: Видео не смотрел, но по описанию очень похоже, что Вам хочется немножечко реактивных потоков. Прочитайте про реактивное программирование. Правда я не знаю насколько хорошо это реализовано в PHP.

Comment: @Oleg, да не не думаю, мне просто каким то макаром нужно запустить одновременно несколько функций. Даже если вопрос поставить так, условно есть файл А и файл Б, они подключены в одном файле В, вот как сделать так что бы А и Б при вызове файла В запустились одновременно, что бы Б не ждал пока А сделает свою работу.

Comment: Случай как раз похож на ваш - надо было сделать пару сотен апи-запросов к сервисам, которые медленно отвечают. https://habr.com/post/278755/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень хотел снять видеоответ, но сейчас, к сожалению, такой возможности нет. Поэтому просто напишу.

Как вы, наверняка, сами заметили, у вас возникли две задачи: создание очереди и обработка задач этой очереди. Существуют различные инструменты для их решения, но я предлагаю смастерить свой велосипед, чтобы, разобравшись, как это работает сделать осознанный выбор (и возможно на этом велосипеде и поехать).

Шаг 1: Создание очереди задач на выполнение.

Используем базу данных (она уже у вас есть, ничего дополнительно устанавливать не потребуется). Добавляем туда простую таблицу с задачами с полями `состояние выполнения`, `данные для задачи`.

Теперь выбираем ID групп и для каждой создаём новую запись в таблице очереди.

Шаг 2: Разгребаем очередь по крону.

Каждые пять секунд запускаем скрипт-воркер (или несколько, с помощью `xargs -P`, например), который лезет в бд и выбирает одну запись из очереди и помечает её как задача `в процессе выполнения`. Если свободных задач в очереди нет, скрипт просто завершается. Если удалось получить задачу, скрипт начинает её выполнять (дёргать сторонние апи, что-то писать в базу, обрабатывать картинки и тд). Важно не допустить, чтобы два одновременно запущенных скрипта начали работать по одной задаче. Для этого используйте блокировки вашей бд. По завершении работы над задачей её можно пометить как `выполнена` или удалить.

Это решение показывает общий принцип работы таких систем. В любом случае вам нужна очередь (в данном случае таблица в бд) и демон, её разгребающий (в данном случае крон).